# Remove unwanted text from Data

Tags: excel, vba

How would I go about removing unwanted text from data that is pull from a website. I have a macro that will pull data from a website but it comes in like this.

Jerry Smith / 193640 / main

Morty Smith / 847478 / main

Rick Sanchez / 747264 / main

Scary Terry / 726950 / side

Ect.

I want to have just the names not the numbers or main/side.

Comment: If the url is public providing the vba code you are using (with url) might help. There might be better ways of handling this in the code rather than in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Offset(, 1).Value = Evaluate("IF({1},LEFT(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ",SEARCH("" / ""," & rng.Address(0, 0) & ",1)-1))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great suggestion. I'll need to modify it a bit but I would haven't figured it out without your help.

Comment: Isn't the condition `IF({1},...` (equalling "do it if true") unnecessary here? - Side note: Fully qualifying a range avoids potentially unwanted results as Excel would take the active sheet if not referred to explicitly. Therefore I'd prefer `rng.parent.Evaluate()` as it then "understands" the sheet reference automatically, otherwise you would have to pass another argument to `rng.Address(External:=True)` or to hard code the sheet reference with a "!" suffix (e.g. "Sheet1!A1:A10") @YasserKhalil

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative via `FilterXML()`**

Using the newer dynamic features you can get output either as spill range or as optional string results.

*You should be able to enter a formula like e.g.*

```
=FILTERXML("<items><i>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A20," /","</i><i>")&"</i></items>","//i[1]")
```

*also via* <kbd>**C**trl</kbd><kbd>**S**hift</kbd><kbd>**E**nter</kbd> as *array formula* (`{=...}`).

```
Sub GetFirstTokens()
'a) define fully qualified range
    With Sheet1                       ' << change to needed sheet Code(Name)
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
'b) define formula
    Dim myFormula As String
    myFormula = "=FILTERXML(""<items><i>""&SUBSTITUTE(@,"" /"",""</i><i>"")&""</i></items>"",""//i[1]"")"
    myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "@", rng.Address(0, 0))
    Debug.Print myFormula
'c) write sheet related spill formula|results to next column
    With rng.Offset(, 1).cells(1, 1)
        .Formula2 = myFormula
        '.Value = .Value           ' << optional: get results instead of a spill range
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Spill range example]

Comment: Intersting I've never tried filterXML before. I learn so much from you guys. Thanks, I know there are many ways to do the same thing. I appreciate it